Python's winreg package is not consistently reading through registry entries
I have the below python code which needs to read through all possible registry entries (under hives) and print comma separated installed applications and versions.
try:
    import winreg  # Python 3.x
except ImportError:
    import _winreg as winreg  # Python 2.7


def query_registry(root_key, uninstall_key):
    apps = []
    try:
        with winreg.OpenKey(root_key, uninstall_key) as key:
            for i in range(0, winreg.QueryInfoKey(key)[0]):
                try:
                    sub_key_name = winreg.EnumKey(key, i)
                    with winreg.OpenKey(key, sub_key_name) as sub_key:
                        name, version = None, None
                        try:
                            name = winreg.QueryValueEx(sub_key, "DisplayName")[0]
                            version = winreg.QueryValueEx(sub_key, "DisplayVersion")[0]
                        except:
                            continue
                        if name and version:
                            # Store as a list of name and version
                            apps.append([name, version])
                except:
                    continue
    except:
        pass
    return apps


def get_hkey_users_subkeys():
    """Get all user SIDs from HKEY_USERS."""
    subkeys = []
    try:
        with winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_USERS, "") as key:
            for i in range(0, winreg.QueryInfoKey(key)[0]):
                try:
                    subkeys.append(winreg.EnumKey(key, i))
                except:
                    continue
    except:
        pass
    return subkeys


def get_installed_apps():
    uninstall_keys = [
        # HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE - 32-bit and 64-bit
        (winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"),
        (winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r"SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"),
        
        # HKEY_CURRENT_USER - 32-bit and 64-bit
        (winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"),
        (winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, r"SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"),
    ]

    # Add HKEY_USERS paths for each SID
    for sid in get_hkey_users_subkeys():
        uninstall_keys.append((winreg.HKEY_USERS, sid + r"\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"))
        uninstall_keys.append((winreg.HKEY_USERS, sid + r"\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"))

    apps = []
    
    # Sequentially query each uninstall key
    for root_key, key in uninstall_keys:
        apps.extend(query_registry(root_key, key))
    
    return apps


if __name__ == "__main__":
    installed_apps = get_installed_apps()
    if installed_apps:
        print("Installed applications and their versions:")
        for app in installed_apps:
            print(f"Name: {app[0]}, Version: {app[1]}")
    else:
        print("No applications found.")

I am aware some applications can be manually installed which might not have registry entries at all (like from a tar/war file) - but we can ignore them for now.
But what I am noticing is that this code is not able to read all registry entries and display the list of installed applications and versions, when the output is compared to a powershell/vbscript code reading from the same registries on the same host.
Is there anything I am missing in the code ? Or any registry key that I am missing ?
